# Jquery Calling Rails Controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a giant check list that is going to have rows of check boxes.  Each row is one event.  When the check box is 'checked' it is replaced with the user's initials and the current date.  I want the user to be able to click on the TD that has the user's info and then have jquery pop up a dialog box which will ask if you want to uncheck this field.

My problem is I have no idea how to call a method from the controller after the dialog box is accepted.  I will need to send the ID and the Category that is passed to the dialog box, to the method also.

Rails View Code:

```
<td style='text-align:center;' class='completed_box' id='<%= check_list.id %>' category='videos_edited'>
                            <div id='videos_edited_<%= check_list.id %>' style='display:none;'>
                                Are you sure you would like to uncheck videos edited recieved?
                            </div>
                            <label>
                                <%= check_list.videos_edited_user_id.initials %> <br />
                                <%= check_list.videos_edited_date.strftime("%-m/%d")  %>
                            </label>
                        </td>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".completed_box").click(function(e){
        id = this.id
        category = $(this).attr('category');
        $("#" + category + "_" + id).dialog({
          resizable: false,
          height:140,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            Yes: function(){
                uncheck(id,category); // This is the function I'm not sure how is going to work 
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            Cancel: function(){
                $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If you want to make a call to a rails method in your controller, you're going to have to make an ajax call.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Use the gon gem to pass the 'uncheck' url to your javascript, so your javascript knows where to post the message.

If you post to an 'uncheck' action with JSON data, with the id of the record to deselect, then your controller can make the change (or better, call model or lib object to make the change), and if successful just end with something like:

```
head :ok
```

If unsuccessful, you may want to render a simple JSON hash with the error message to display, with possibly a different status code like 422 - Unprocessable entity. In your jQuery Ajax, include an error event handler to display the error message if it failed, or recheck the box, or whatever you want to have happen.